# How to map state back to component in Vue.js AWS Amplify auth page

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, vuex, aws-amplify

I am building an authentication page with Vue.js, Vuex, and AWS Amplify.

This auth page is based off Erik Hanchett's AWS Auth Example (https://github.com/ErikCH/Aws-auth-example/blob/master/src/components/HelloWorld.vue). Erik's original demo utilized Vuex for state management, but for the sake of simplicity only employs the `state` handler in the store.js file.

I am attempting to reconfigure this demo so that the various methods and hooks in `HelloWorld.vue` are set up to also dispatch actions and commit mutations.

So far, I have been successful in setting up the `findUser()` method in `HelloWorld.vue` to dispatch actions, pass `user` and `signedIn` as payloads to their respective `action` handlers, and then commit mutations.

However, my issue now pertains to the `computed` property in the `HelloWorld` component.

Erik's original demo returns the state directly to the component using `return this.$store.state.signedIn` as seen in the `computed` property. Based on my experience with Vuex in other projects, I would normally use a `mapState` helper to map directly to the state.

Is it correct in this project to use `this.$store.state.signedIn` to return the state? Or should I use `mapState`? If so, how can I reconfigure this `computed` property in order to employ `mapState` to map directly to `signedIn`?

My code is below:

**HelloWorld.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <div v-if="!signedIn">
      <amplify-authenticator></amplify-authenticator>
    </div>
    <div v-if="signedIn">
      <Home></Home>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'
import { AmplifyEventBus } from 'aws-amplify-vue';
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import Home from '../components/Home.vue'
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  components: {
    Home
  },
  data() {
    return {
      login: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  created(){
    this.findUser();
    AmplifyEventBus.$on('authState', info => {
      if(info === "signedIn") {
        this.findUser();
      } else {
        this.$store.state.signedIn = false;
        this.$store.state.user = null;
      }
    });
  },
  computed: {
    signedIn(){
      return this.$store.state.signedIn;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async findUser() {
      try {
        const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
        let signedIn = true
        this.$store.dispatch('setUser', user)
        this.$store.dispatch('setSignedIn', signedIn)
      }
      catch(err) {
        let signedIn = false
        this.$store.dispatch('setSignedIn', signedIn)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user: null,
    signedIn: false
  },
  mutations: {
    setUser(state, user) {
      state.user = user
    },
    setSignedIn(state, signedIn) {
      state.signedIn = signedIn
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setUser: (context, user) => {
      context.commit('setUser', user)
    },
    setSignedIn: (context, signedIn) => {
      context.commit('setSignedIn', signedIn)
    }
  }
})
```

**Home.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="goodbye">
    <h1>HOME</h1><br>
      <amplify-sign-out></amplify-sign-out>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data() {
    return {
      login: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  methods: {
    signOut() {
      Auth.signOut()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mapState` helper is just sugar syntax for not repeating multiple times the whole `this.$store.state.foo` piece of code.

You can certainly use `mapState` like this

```js
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

computed: mapState([
  // map this.signedIn to this.$store.state.signedIn
  'signedIn'
])
```

Or like this if you want to also use local properties besides the ones of `mapState`

```js
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

computed: 
   localComputed () { /* ... */ },
   ...mapState([
   // map this.signedIn to this.$store.state.signedIn
     'signedIn'
   ])
```

Here are the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html) for more information on this.

Comment: thank you for this answer! Would you be willing to take a look at another Vue.js/AWS-amplify issue? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59001855/how-to-retrieve-currentuser-data-with-vue-js-aws-amplify-and-mongodb